# Relation between transverse velocity of sound and Young's modulus in solids

Tags: waves, solid-state-physics, solid-mechanics

There is a relation which holds in solids:
$$v_{t}=\sqrt{\frac{E}{\rho}}$$
where $v_t$ is the the velocity of sound (transversal elastic waves), and $E$ and $\rho$ are the Young's modulus and density of the medium respectively.

How would I derive this or can someone give me a reference where the derivation is obtained?
(I would guess somehow connecting the wave equation and Hooke's law maybe?)

Answer (score 5):

All you need is the Navier's equation of motion (*you can consult it in any book of elasticity*)

> $$ \rho \frac{\partial^2 w}{ \partial t^2 } = \mu \nabla^2w + (\lambda + \mu)\nabla\nabla.w $$

Naturally, you can decompose a wave $ w$ in a transversal and a longitudinal part:

$$ w = w_L + w_T $$

with the following properties :

$$ \nabla \times w_L = 0$$ 
$$ \nabla .w_T = 0 $$

If we focused only in the transversal part, retaking the Navier equation we have:

$$ \rho \frac{\partial^2 w_T}{ \partial t^2 } = \mu \nabla^2 w_T  $$

Now you can remember that the general wave equation is

> $$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial t^2 } = c^2 \nabla^2 u $$

where c is the phase velocity of the wave $ u $

So, that's it

$$ v_T = \sqrt \frac \mu\rho$$

I hope you help

J.

Comment: Did you understand it? ? If so, you can thank the answer and the effort

Answer (score 0):

To add to J0KerSpin's good answer, $\mu$ is not the elastic modulus, but rather the Lamé parameter and is equivalent to the shear modulus, $G$, rather than the Young's modulus for linear isotropic solids.

This question may be in regards to using ultrasound to measure the elastic modulus. Usually, ultrasound measurements apply longitudinal waves, $w_L$ rather than transverse waves, $w_T$, in order to measure the longitudinal velocity through the sample. Going back to the Navier-Cauchy equation, we have:

\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{\partial^2w}{\partial t^2} = \mu \nabla^2 w + (\lambda + \mu) \nabla (\nabla \cdot w)
\end{equation}

We use the vector identity:

\begin{equation}
\nabla(\nabla \cdot w) = \nabla^2w + \nabla \times w
\end{equation}

With longitudinal waves, we have the property:
$$
\nabla \times w_L = 0
$$
Therefore, applying these equations to the Navier-Cauchy equation, we get:

$$
\frac{\rho}{2\mu+\lambda} \frac{\partial^2w_L}{\partial t^2} = \nabla^2 w_L 
$$

This is the wave equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2w_L}{\partial t^2} = v_L \nabla^2 w_L 
$$

Where $v_L$ is the longitudinal velocity. Thus we get that the longitudinal velocity is:

$$
v_L = \sqrt{\frac{2\mu + \lambda}{\rho}}
$$

[1] shows that the Lamé parameters can be written in terms of the Poisson's ratio $\nu$ and the Young's modulus, $E$ for linear isotropic systems:

$$
\lambda = \frac{E\nu}{(1+\nu) (1-2\nu)} \\
$$

$$
\nu = \frac{E}{2(1+\nu)}
$$

Thus we end up with the relationship between the longitudinal velocity, the Young's modulus, and the Poisson's ratio:

$$
v_L = \sqrt{\frac{E (1-\nu)}{\rho(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}}
$$

This result does NOT agree with the commonly cited result that was presented in the question of this post, $v_L = \sqrt{E/\rho}$. However, I have seen this equation being used in the literature, see [2] for example, and some have argued it is the more correct equation to use when trying to extract the Young's modulus from ultrasound velocity measurements, see [3].

Best,
-Jacob

References:
[1] https://web.mit.edu/16.20/homepage/3_Constitutive/Constitutive_files/module_3_with_solutions.pdf

[2] https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsami.6b06612

[3] http://koski.ucdavis.edu/BRILLOUIN/CRYSTALS/LongitudinalModulus.html